# Does $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {f(x)}{|x|} \leq M $ ,for some real $M$ ,imply that $f(x)\leq |x| M $?

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, functions, convergence-divergence

Just to restate my question as in the title:

> Does $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {f(x)}{|x|} \leq M $ , for some real $M$, imply that $f(x)\leq |x| M $ ?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by $f(x) \leq |x| M$?   For all $x$?  For small $x$?  Well you might want to consider a simple example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality won't hold on any neighborhood of $0$. For instance, 
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2}{|x|} \le 0$$ but $x^2 \le 0|x|$ is false for all $x$ except $x=0$.